# wp_editor call with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress plugin that manages a database. 
The database has a table that has the id field name and descr. 
I have a php file that has two buttons, one and another rule change. 
When you click on the switch, the button triggers a javascript event that produces an ajax request cleaning a div and puts the contents of about.php Archiving

File ajax.js

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/project/wp-content/plugins/admin/about.php",
        data: {"id":id},
        success: function(data)
        {
             $("#admin div").empty();
             $("#admin div").append(data);
        }
  });
```

File about.php

```
<?php

$descr = $_POST['id']
$html = "<div>".wp_editor('','textarea', array('textarea_name' => $descr, 'media_buttons' => false))."</div>";
echo $html;

?>
```

In the file there is about one textarea I implement the wp_editor, however when ajax returns the contents of the textarea about.php looks like this:

[image]

How do I bring the features of textarea along with the buttons via ajax?

Comment: Maybe you're doing Ajax wrong, and maybe you don't need to generate a new `wp_editor` at each call. What exactly is the goal? Are you sure you're not running into a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Can you provide more context and a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You should look into WordPress's ajax system, it can simplify your plugin: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins